# CasperJS - How to click on the provided Element

Tags: casperjs

This is the Div with UL on the webpage.

```xml
<div id='sites'>
  <ul style="display: block;">
    <li data-product-id="55">
      <a href="#">Test1<br><em class="environment">Production</em></a>
    </li>
    <li data-product-id="99">
      <a href="#">Test2<br><em class="environment">Production</em></a>
    </li>
    <li data-product-id="98">
      <a href="#">Test3<br><em class="environment">Production</em></a>
    </li>
    <li data-product-id="61">
      <a href="#">Test4<br><em class="environment">Production</em></a>
    </li>
    <li data-product-id="97">
      <a href="#">Test5<br><em class="environment">Production</em></a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      Test6<br><em class="environment">Production</em> <a class="flat button" href="/product_center">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The page loads with **Test6 ul** by-default and I want to click on **Test5**.

The CSS locator provided by Firepath is `"#sites>ul>li>a"`. So I tried this in casperjs:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.start('http://localhost:8080', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.page.injectJs('jquery.js');
    this.evaluate(function (){
          $("#sites>ul>li")[4].click();
    });
    this.capture('screenshot.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

The title that comes up is always of the current page. It should have clicked on Test5 and fetched the title of the Test5 Page.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try #sites .active as the selector

I'd do

`this.click('#sites .active')` instead of

```
casper.page.injectJs('jquery.js');
  this.evaluate(function ()
          {
          $("#sites>ul>li")[4].click();
       });
```

edit for comment:

try this then

```
#sites li:nth-child(5) a
```

Comment: I need to click on Test5. The .active one is Test6

Answer (score 1):

square bracket for JS array returns "object HTMLDivElement"; while .slice() returns array.

click() function normally coming along with array objects.

So your codes should go to:

```
$("#sites ul li").slice(4,5).click()
```